# Check how many elements have been added and removed from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have two arrays which are not similar in structure,

```js
    let newArray = [{
    name: "name1",
    age: 24,
    place: etc
    }]

    let previousArray = [{
    name: "name1",
    age: 24,
    place: etc
    }, {
    name: "name2",
    age: 23,
    place: "hello"
    country: "test"
    }]
```

I want to check how many elements are newly added and how many have been removed from the new list. I used the deepdiff package, but it tends to compare characters.

For this, the answer should be 1 element removed and 0 elements added to the new list.

Comment: When elements are added, are they always appended ?  When an element is removed, all the other elements move down one, yes ?  If an element is removed and later an element which is exactly the same is added, how do you want to count that ?  Can we assume all elements are different ?

Comment: Yea, there no specific order on how the elements are added, as this is generated by another program.

Comment: Then I suggest throwing the old list into a dictionary (or hash table) and reading the new list against that, to see which elements of the new list match any elements in the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the `previousArray` and check if the object is present in the `newArray`, if not then increment `removeCount`. Similary, iterate over the `newArray` to get the count of `added` objects.

```js
let newArray = [{
    name: "name1",
    age: 24,
    place: "etc"
}]

let previousArray = [{
    name: "name1",
    age: 24,
    place: "etc"
}, {
    name: "name2",
    age: 23,
    place: "hello",
    country: "test"
}];

let removeCount = 0;
let addCount = 0;

previousArray.forEach(preObj => {
    const found = newArray.find(newObj => JSON.stringify(newObj) == JSON.stringify(preObj));
    if(!found) {
        removeCount++;
        console.log(`Removed`, preObj);
    }
});

newArray.forEach(newObj => {
    const found = previousArray.find(prevObj => JSON.stringify(prevObj) == JSON.stringify(newObj));
    if(!found) {
        addCount++;
        console.log(`added`, newObj);
    }
});

console.log('Added: ', addCount,' Removed: ', removeCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you only care about number of added/removed items:

```js
const newArray = [
  { name: 'name1', age: 24 },
  { name: 'name3', age: 25, },
  { name: 'name4', age: 25 }
]

const prevArray = [
  { name: 'name1', age: 24 },
  { name: 'name2', age: 23 }
]

// define which items can be considered equal
const isEqual = (a, b) => a.name === b.name && a.age === b.age

// find out amount of common items between two arrays
// (the ones that haven't been added nor removed)
const commonItemsLength = newArray.filter(newItem => prevArray.find(prevItem => isEqual(newItem, prevItem))).length

// subtract common items length from each arrays length
const removedCount = prevArray.length - commonItemsLength
const addedCount = newArray.length - commonItemsLength

console.log(`removed: ${removedCount}`, `added: ${addedCount}`)
```